# Minimum value of $2^{2x}+6\cdot 2^x +18$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, quadratics

> Minimum value of $$2^{2x}+6\cdot 2^x +18.$$

It looks like the quadratic equation $$t^2+6t+18=(t+3)^2+9.$$

So the minimum is $9$ if we complete the square, but there is no such $x$ which will give us $2^x=-3$.

So the answer should be $18$ as $2^x>0$ for all $x$! Am I correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write:

$$2^{2x}+6\cdot 2^x +18=(2^x+3)^2+9$$

And see that the minimum happens when $2^x \rightarrow 0$ once $2^x >0$.

So in this case we have infimum (not minimum) and it is $18$.

Comment: +1 as I like the use of "infimum",  which is exactly appropriate here.

Comment: @Deepak, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The function
$$f(x)=2^{2x}+6\cdot 2^x +18$$
is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$: if $x_1>x_2$ then
$$f(x_1)-f(x_2)=(4^{x_1}-4^{x_2})+6\cdot(2^{x_1}-2^{x_2})>0.$$
Therefore the greatest lower bound is
$$\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=18.$$
Note that $f$ does not attain the value $18$ so you can not say that $18$ is the minimum value.

Comment: Do you mean greatest lower bound rather than least upper bound?

Comment: @Deepak Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are. However the value is not a minimum but an infimum because this value is taken after
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}2^{2x}+6\cdot 2^x +18=18$$ (*for all negative real $x$ you have 
$2^{2x}+6\cdot 2^x +18\gt18$*)